# Why does my LaTeX documentclass declaration produce a fatal error?

Tags: latex

I am writing an article for a university course. As I was finishing up I went to the preamble to change the options for my document class ({memoir}). I wanted to change from [openright] to [openany] to get rid of some blank pages. After changing the declaration, I am unable to recompile. I keep getting a fatal error

I have changed the declaration back to [openright], but to no effect.
I have changed the declaration to [oneside], but to no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Here's my documentclass declaration in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,dvipsnames,twoside,openright]{memoir}
```

Comment: When I do a document with this documentclass, I have no problem latexing it. It must be in another part of the document. Maybe try to find the exact line  of the problem. Generally latex indicates it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error message you're getting?